# Error while reading the first line of a text file in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to take out the first line of a file called `id.txt` and setting it to a variable.

```
Set /p requestid=<id.txt
```

Which is giving me an error as below:

```
Set /p requestid=0<id.txt 
Requestida was unexpected at this time.
```

Could anyone suggest me on this.

1. Why there is zero in front of shift left operator
2. What is the reason that the variable is not getting set with the first line of `id.txt` file.

Even though when I hit the same command over cmd it is working but in batch file it is getting stuck at this line with the above error.

Here is the full script:

```
cd C:\scripts\
dir .csr;.pem /B >csr.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\scripts\csr.txt) do call :next

:next
If "%1"=="" goto end
certReq -submit -config machine_name -attrib "CertificateTemplate:XYZ" %1 %1.cer >id.txt
set /p Requid=<C:\scripts\id.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %a in ("%Requid%") do set Requid1=%a
Certutil -resubmit %Requid1%

:end
```

Comment: Request id is : 680

Comment: Like this there are several lines in the file

Comment: In order for your issue to be resolved, you need to provide more information than a single command line along with the generated message. As it currently stands, based on the information you've provided, the issue cannot be replicated, given a first line containing either `680` or `Request id is : 680`, (even using UTF8 with BOM and/or using one of only CR or LF line endings), shouldn't generate that message, so your question is currently off topic. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54864137/edit) to provide more information, thank you.

Comment: @VijaSingh, I've transferred your script content into your question. I'm a little disturbed however because what you've posted cannot work. Not only is your `Dir` command wrong; _the content of `csr.txt` will be `File Not Found`_, you're calling a label without an argument, meaning that `%1` will be empty and the script would `GoTo :end`. Based on your provided content, you appear to be reading a string `Request id is : 680` and looking for the second space delimited token `id` within it. Please post the correct script for the issue you've reported and update your question properly; thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:
The `0` means `STDIN` (standard input). Check [Standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) for the concept.
`0` is a [File descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) for `stdin`.
It's automatically added by the batch system, and it's not an error.

Question 2:
Your syntax seems okay, and I tested it's working. There must be other error.
However you can change it to another way:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (id.txt) do set "requestid=%%i" & goto :endfor
:endfor
```

Comment: cd C:\scripts\
dir *.csr;*.pem /B >csr.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\scripts\csr.txt) do call :next 

:next
If "%1"=="" goto end
certReq -submit -config machine_name -attrib "CertificateTemplate:XYZ" %1 %1.cer >id.txt
set /p Requid=<C:\scripts\id.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %a in ("%Requid%") do set Requid1=%a
Certutil -resubmit %Requid1%
:end

Comment: @VijaySingh You used `%a` in your 2nd `for` command, try change it to `%%a`, see if it works. Also it's better quote the file path: `set /p Requid=<"C:\scripts\id.txt"`.

Comment: I tries what you said...but the error is still the same as the error is itself in the above line (set /p command). Please advise

Comment: @VijaySingh Could you paste your code at the end of your question? So we may see it clearly, I might missed something.  Also you can try use the method in my answer, to replace the `set /p` line. (remember the `:endfor` is also needed, otherwise it will set last line instead of the first)

Comment: Thank you so much Tiw... It worked out with the alternative of set /p which u gave it earlier.